# can I provide a default value for keyof parameter in typescript?

Tags: typescript

Trying to enforce an optional, defaulted parameter on a generic method that must be a property of the passed object. Here is an example:

```
function doIt<T>(target: T, propA: keyof T, propB: keyof T): string {
    return `${target[propA]} ${target[propB]}`;
}
```

But, in the above example, I would like to default `propA` and `propB` to `foo` and `bar` for example:

```
function doIt<T>(target: T, propA: keyof T = 'foo', propB: keyof T = 'bar'): string {
    return `${target[propA]} ${target[propB]}`;
}
```

But when I do that, it complains that `Type '"bar"' is not assignable to type 'keyof T'.ts(2322)` which makes sense.
Even if I add a default type to `T`, it still doesn't work:

```
function doIt<T = { foo: string; bar: string }>(target: T, propA: keyof T = 'foo', propB: keyof T = 'bar'): string {
    return `${target[propA]} ${target[propB]}`;
}
```

Basically, I want to be able to do:

```
doIt({foo: 'jane', bar: 'doe'}); // should return 'jane doe'
doIt({zoo: 'jane', baz: 'doe'}); // should fail compilation
doIt({zoo: 'jane', baz: 'doe'}, 'zoo', 'baz'}); // should return 'jane doe'
```

Any ways of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't easily use default parameter values for this without running afoul of the type checker.

The simplest way to get what you're looking for is probably to use [overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) to describe the different intended ways to call `doIt()`, like this:

```
namespace Overloads {
  function doIt<T>(target: T, propA: keyof T, propB: keyof T): string;
  function doIt<T extends { bar: any }>(target: T, propA: keyof T): string;
  function doIt<T extends { foo: any; bar: any }>(target: T): string;
  function doIt(target: any, propA?: keyof any, propB?: keyof any): string {
    if (typeof propA === "undefined") propA = "foo";
    if (typeof propB === "undefined") propB = "bar";
    return `${target[propA]} ${target[propB]}`;
  }

  console.log(doIt({ foo: "jane", bar: "doe" })); // jane doe
  console.log(doIt({ zoo: "jane", baz: "doe" })); // error!
  // ┌─────────────> ~~~~~~~~~~~~
  // "zoo" not expected (although I'm surprised it doesn't complain about missing foo/bar)
  console.log(doIt({ zoo: "jane", baz: "doe" }, "zoo", "baz")); // jane doe
  console.log(doIt({ zoo: "jane", bar: "doe" }, "zoo")); // jane doe
}
```

That works the way you want.  Note that the three call signatures correspond to different numbers of parameters, and they each have different [constraints](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints) on the generic type parameter `T`.  (You may wish to use `string` instead of `any` as property types, there... not sure)

Note that in the implementation signature I've got `target` as `any`, `propA`, and `propB` as `(keyof any) | undefined`.  So the implementation won't be particularly type-safe here.  Overloads don't really help with implementation type safety; they are more for the caller's benefit.  If you tried to make the implementation generic you'd run into similar problems where the compiler can't verify that `"foo"` is assignable to `keyof T`, etc.

Also note that we can't use default parameter values in overload signatures, but that's fine... we can just do that assignment ourselves inside the function implementation.  If the parameters are `undefined`, reassign them.

---

Another way to do this is to use TypeScript's support for treating [rest parameters as tuple types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#tuples-in-rest-parameters-and-spread-expressions), including [optional tuple elements](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#optional-elements-in-tuple-types):

```
namespace ConditionalTupleParameters {
  function doIt<T>(
    target: T,
    ...[propA, propB]: T extends { foo: any; bar: any }
      ? [(keyof T)?, (keyof T)?] // propA and propB are optional
      : T extends { bar: any }
        ? [keyof T, (keyof T)?] // propA is required, propB is optional
        : [keyof T, keyof T] // propA and propB are optional
  ): string {
    if (typeof propA === "undefined") propA = "foo";
    if (typeof propB === "undefined") propB = "bar";
    return `${target[propA]} ${target[propB]}`;
  }

  console.log(doIt({ foo: "jane", bar: "doe" })); // jane doe
  console.log(doIt({ zoo: "jane", baz: "doe" })); // error!
  // ┌──────> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  // expected 3 arguments, got 1
  console.log(doIt({ zoo: "jane", baz: "doe" }, "zoo", "baz")); // jane doe
  console.log(doIt({ zoo: "jane", bar: "doe" }, "zoo")); // jane doe
}
```

This works similarly to the overloads.  It's fairly ugly looking, which is not great.  But, the implementation is actually relatively type-safe, where `target` is still known to be type `T`, and `propA` and `propB` end up being `keyof T` after checking against `undefined`.

---

Okay, hope one of those helps.  Good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play//#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEB5AbhATgGwPYgBMokBvAKCSQDMBXYeAFwEtdgkDcBJBgHgBUAfAAoGITAHMIDAFxI+AGiQxMuGAEFZAawgBPXFTmLlqgEJbd+uQEpZUBpibBxAbgrU6jFmw7d+SCAAeDBDARKRIAEZisiDAOkgAvsKiElKyCkoq6uZ6Bnw2SHYOTq6UtPTMrOxcvHz+QSFhJNS4uDFxzpHRSLHxSSJikjLWtvaOLm7lnlU+DAOpw71GWWoA-DmWS5mm60jauT1xBUXjpG6UTAYiOjAQlsbqSAC8L0gARHQEEFSOEARvVm2jye7yorTepUoSEuSGut3uWRMz1eH1C31+-0BDyRILeUUwEPOSEwUhomDYAAMACQkFJDADaDzUAF0EkgaXSpIzEayKZCEmQ3PBWFBcNgIAA6PDiISzITNMFtd4AK1iEDeinxsjeHHViSsVk6AHojUhVcBkLqhSKxZLpbKavKkAAvVra83qzUgZ3a3VvfWGpAm-yYFSYACEbmDgBhSQAApPGE4mEwIkAA-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-KCpQwobra267o6Cpur+FrHsJOpAf6CQGhBZpqs+r47fae4uodbweid3qAcBV1uVgYaRpQMZJrGKZZqDYPg2DOalhA5baQAzBl4g0JAwAMFAijiMWSAAIz3Vuj37c9SqvX+J6fRdoHXu8t7gW5UFAXj757V++4vW9-7kxe7xgd9j63dBgpkEAA)

Comment: Yeah, was heading down the overloads path after I asked. Definitely the right answer. Definitely intrigued with your conditional tuples... though I must say that I don't think anybody else on my team would come close to understanding it if I were to use that approach. Overloads are already a stretch for some ;)

Answer (score 0):

What about casting the default value?

**Simplified example**

```
const doIt = <T = { id: string }>(key: keyof T = 'id' as keyof T) => {}
```

**Example from question**

```
function doIt<T>(target: T, propA: keyof T = 'foo' as keyof T, propB: keyof T = 'bar' as keyof T): string {
    return `${target[propA]} ${target[propB]}`;
}
```