# How to add default value in function parameters in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

I am trying to add the last piece of type in my function, but typescript complained whatever I do. I know there is a way to solve it, and need your help.

```
export const getPropertiesArray = <T extends object, K extends keyof T>(data: T[], property: K) => {
    return data.map(item => item[property]).sort();
};
```

This is my function and I need to add a default value to `property`, in this case, the default value is "ID".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Passing default "ID" is not assignable to constraint of `object`.
Indeed you should assume that ID is always a key of your object.

Here is a workaround:

```js
// T extends { ID: any } - You may replace any by your ID type
export const getPropertiesArray = <T extends { ID: any }>(
  data: T[],
  property: keyof T = 'ID'
) => {
  return data.map(item => item[property]).sort()
}
```

Comment: `getPropertiesArray(props.charterers.payload, 'key')` calling the function with other key than 'ID' throws an error .  *Argument of type '"key"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"ID" | undefined'.*

Comment: Yes that was the case , typescript couldn't infer type for that .

Answer (score 4):

***In general*** the answer to the question as stated is simple - the format for a default parameter is `myParam = "default value"`, so for example

```
function myFunc(param1 = "default value") {
    //...
}
```

You can read more about default parameters in Typescript here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#optional-and-default-parameters

***HOWEVER:*** the OP's particular scenario involves a [`keyof` parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html), which requires special handling. See [Simon Bruneaud's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61641130/422845) for this.

Comment: In that case, tslint throws an error `K declared but its value never used`

Comment: Oh I see - and I'm guessing you can't just make the 2nd parameter of type String? That's probably what's causing the error, since you're passing in a String as the default value....optionally can you typecast, something like `property = (K) "ID"`?

Comment: Could you please update your answer with your suggestion? I didn't get your mind

Comment: Updated, but also with a little more searching, I found this question, which I think is your core issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57151263/can-i-provide-a-default-value-for-keyof-parameter-in-typescript

Comment: I checked it out. I didn't like the solution. I believe it can be solved very easily. Anyway, thanks a lot.