# Typescript dynamic keys return value

Tags: typescript

I want to build an object with two keys based on the provided key names.

```
function dynamicKeys<KeyOne extends PropertyKey, KeyTwo extends PropertyKey>(
  keyOne?: KeyOne,
  keyTwo?: KeyTwo
) {
  const normalizeKeyOne = keyOne ?? ("foo" as const);
  const normalizeKeyTwo = keyTwo ?? ("bar" as const);

  return {
    [normalizeKeyOne]: {},
    [normalizeKeyTwo]: [],
  } as const;
}
```

The issue is that the above code returns a general type:

```
{
    readonly [x: string]: {};
}
```

Is there any way to make it return the following type:

```
const v = dynamicKeys(); // return type should be { foo, bar }
const v2 = dynamicKeys('baz', 'boo'); // return type should be { baz, boo }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few things going on here, but the main problem you're facing is TypeScript rarely gives strong types to objects with computed keys.  In your case the key is of a generic type, so you get the behavior listed as a design limitation in [microsoft/TypeScript#21030](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21030): the key type is widened all the way to `string`.  A number of other GitHub issues touch on this, notably [microsoft/TypeScript#13948](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13948), which is still an open issue.  It's not clear that anything is going to get implemented here in the near future, so we'll have to work around it by figuring out the desired type and [asserting](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) that the value is of that type.

---

One possible implementation of `dynamicKeys()` looks like this:

```
function dynamicKeys<K1 extends PropertyKey = "foo", K2 extends PropertyKey = "bar">(
    keyOne?: K1,
    keyTwo?: K2
) {
    const normalizeKeyOne = keyOne ?? ("foo" as K1);
    const normalizeKeyTwo = keyTwo ?? ("bar" as K2);

    return {
        [normalizeKeyOne]: {},
        [normalizeKeyTwo]: [],
    } as { [P in K1 | K2]: P extends K1 ? {} : [] };
}
```

Let's verify that it works for normal use cases:

```
console.log(dynamicKeys().foo); // {}
console.log(dynamicKeys().bar.length); // 0


console.log(dynamicKeys("baz").baz); // {}
console.log(dynamicKeys().bar.length); // 0

console.log(dynamicKeys("baz", "qux").baz); // {}
console.log(dynamicKeys("baz", "qux").qux.length); // 0
```

Looks good.

---

In that implementation, I'm using a few not-always-correct tricks.

The first is that I'm giving [default specifications for the generic parameters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) so that if the compiler cannot infer them it falls back to `"foo"` and `"bar"` for `K1` and `K2` respectively.  Such failed inference happens when someone calls `dynamicKeys()` without one or more of its parameters.  The reason this isn't quite correct is that someone can always manually specify the generic parameters when calling `dynamicKeys()`, and the compiler won't complain:

```
// don't do this
try {
    dynamicKeys<"boo", "hiss">().hiss.length;
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e); // dynamicKeys().hiss is undefined
}
```

The second is that the return type, `{ [P in K1 | K2]: P extends K1 ? {} : [] }` is a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) which has keys for every element in the union `K1 | K2`.  For any key in `K1`, the value type is `{}`, and for any key in `K2`, the value type is `[]`.  This is fine for the common case where `K1` and `K2` are each some single [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types).  The reason this isn't quite correct is that someone can pass in parameters where `K1` or `K2` are themselves [union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types), and then the compiler will mistakenly think that the output has more keys than it actually does:

```
// don't do this
const oops = dynamicKeys(
    Math.random() < 0.5 ? "one" : "two",
    Math.random() < 0.5 ? "three" : "four"
);
/* const oops: {
    one: {};
    two: {};
    three: [];
    four: [];
} */
try {
    console.log(oops.three.length + oops.four.length);
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e); // oops.three is undefined (or maybe oops.four is undefined)
}
```

Each of these issues can themselves be worked around or avoided, at the cost of making things even more complicated.  You can deal with the "possibly bad default" behavior by following one of the approaches in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57151263/can-i-provide-a-default-value-for-keyof-parameter-in-typescript).  You can deal with the "union of keys" behavior by following one of the approaches in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65724066/forbid-explicit-type-parameters-or-constrain-union-type-parameters-for-more-type). It depends on where you want to stop.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAEwJ5gIYFsYQNICmqAzgDx4CMiBAHlAWMsYgAoBOcADgW1KoakQBeRACJgcOKIA0iPACZqdBk1YduvfkWFiARhjaiAfAAoAsAChE1xAGsiAeTAEA-AC45FaZZt2iAFQB3OHc5eUsASkQAbx8bCARiKEQwODYsDAAbGAAvAgEnAh17VELEFxdEE3FJUUQMZkoIgG446wSwJJS0jOy8gSC4YoDg8srq-UN6xvkWyzbENgIoEDYkWKtfGwBtVPSs3PzHZwBdD2iAX29NrcRdnoP+kbgzu5Pr3wvpmLuWRBgkJREAAfMKvP60eiMRpUSqXRAebYnRAXVoWC7zCyYjrEOCZAgAOkycAA5iY0JgcPgiMQTBECRI4C1EAB6FkxDEWHF4wnEskU7C4AS0+mTIkMElQAAWzLZiAADJjLNz8UTSeT0ILqSQJhgcqJRXrZezLsrEjy1fzNVThXSCWL8WBJTLmqz2YqsVzzaq+RrKUKabr9bJRABHEA0A32o2uuWmr2dC2+gU2wOifTBsThyP07Pip3S40KpUWOXIBAAcmS5cQ0pgxEsUDYgg2vhTAZIpHTtRDUvrxGMdr7xGI+edaK+EAwUAgUqqBCirfi3t56oXsfZ7e1IoJw+Y9cQ4GQBGAAIIyEsnMxZcr1aGdYbCa6kk4zBEW9tCwAstOpQS2BgjBwFgdKIKQCoEgArOUYgIAQdQeKIUDBDI36-v+gHliBUTgfKUEwUhUpLPBCJiBIqyiJEaIsgAVIgOLJC+xDnAscHnKiCzIXA7For40rEYiJy8TY5FsIJE6IDRLKNs2MQLCqq5kkxBL8QQvIStKiAANSIMpoljoWElTjOc4mAuck3PRK6WmZRbKapRQHkeJ5nsgVRpIgGSoLoRR6XAqz-Mwzmns4yARJeQA)